# Calling the same function twice using plain javascript and jquery, at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What problems could arise from executing this piece of code?

```js
function function1() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
      $("button").hide();
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='button' onclick='function1()'>Okay</button>
```

Comment: *"...using javascript and jquery, at the same time?"* makes no sense. jQuery is a function library, not a language. Unless you're using TypeScript or CoffeeScript or something, when you're using jQuery, you're using JavaScript.

Comment: @Mos - please allow us to edit your question - especially when your have formatting and typo issues

Comment: Putting a document.ready inside a function you execute on click also does not make any sense

Comment: Sure go ahead @mplungjan

Answer (score 2):

> What problems could arise from executing this piece of code?

In this particular case? It'll be confusing and frustrating to the user. Your code waits until the user clicks the button before hooking up a second click handler. Then when the user clicks the button a *second* time, the button will disappear. That's probably for the best, though, because if it didn't disappear but did something else instead, every click would make it do that thing one more time:

- First click = seemingly nothing happens
- Second click = the thing happens once
- Third click = the thing happens twice
- Fourth click = the thing happens three times

...because you're constantly adding more click handlers.

Pick one. Either use DOM0 `onxyz`-attributes, or hook up your handlers with modern event handling (via jQuery or not, that's up to you). The latter is generally a better idea.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for the explanation. I dint know it would iterate.